# Problem using PHP null coalescing together with ternary operator to reset a Session

Tags: php, session, conditional-operator, unset, null-coalescing-operator

I am trying to reset the Session with the below code:

```
<?= 
$_SESSION['pettySuccess']??''; 
(($_SESSION['pettySuccess']??'')=='') ?'': unset($_SESSION['pettySuccess']); 
?>
```

the idea behind my code is for the pettySuccess session to reset the session when it doesn't evaluate as ' '
but here I am getting a syntax error. The weird thing is when I changed the unset() method
to session_unset(), I dont have a syntax error anymore, the error I got now was that 'the session_unset() does not accept any attributes' and my intention was never to reset all my session variables.

Comment: Unset is not a function and it doesn't return anything, so it cant be used as value for ternary operator. Also you are using ternary operator in a bad way, because you are not assigning nothing. You are also using  a loose comparison so the unset will be executed also for valuse as NULL, 0 , false, etc. Try: `if ($_SESSION['pettySuccess'] !== '') unset($_SESSION['pettySuccess']);`

Comment: I think you might need to edit your comment a bit so I can understand all your points, but with I was able to pick up I figured what was wrong and it is about the unset() not being usable as a value in ternary operation, I still don't understand why session_unset() works just fine and unset() doesn't.

Comment: @okunadeyusuf *session_unset()* returns a boolean value and it can be evaluated.
To be more precise, *unset()* regardless of whether it is considered a function or not, returns *void*, like *var_dump()* or *echo* and the *void* value can't be used in expressions.

Comment: oh, I understand now, if I were to stick with my code I could use something like this then :  <?= $_SESSION['pettySuccess']??''; (($_SESSION['pettySuccess']??'') !=='') ?$_SESSION['pettySuccess']='':''
; ?>

Comment: `$_SESSION['pettySuccess']??'';` by itself doesn't accomplish anything, you aren't storing the generated value anywhere.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález that was a Null coalescing operator, the idea was to do nothing whenever $_SESSION['pettySuccess'] is null or not set prior to it.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. The easiest way to do nothing is to not write any code at all.

Comment: Alright 'nothing' was a wrong use of word, Let me explain. If pettySuccess was not declared in session, the outputted value is reset to an empty string, meaning that this is a conditional logic that is meant to be useful only when a value is stored in pettySuccess session variable.  The reason I added the condition to reset the value to an empty string was to escape the undefine rule error whenever my logic condition was not met.

Answer (score 1):

`unset()` is a statement and not a function, so it cannot be used directly within a ternary operator. You can use the following code:

```php
if (isset($_SESSION['pettySuccess']) && $_SESSION['pettySuccess'] !== '') {
    unset($_SESSION['pettySuccess']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your business logic is, but I suspect all you need is:

```
unset($_SESSION['pettySuccess']);
```

[unset()](https://php.net/unset) is a language construct so it's able to detect and ignore missing variables (something that regular functions cannot do), and it actually does (yes, it's unfortunately not documented).